# My ip is redirecting to www-ip

Tags: redirects, 301-redirect

I have a redirection rule that redirect my any domain.com request to `www.domain.com`, But if i try open my domain with ip it redirects to www.ip/.
I want my site to open when i try to open with ip.

for reference this is what my `htaccess` looks like.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$
https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Can you clarify if you have a single domain you want to redirect, or if you have multiple domains? Also should access via the IP redirect to a domain (if so, which?) or just leave the IP as it is?

Comment: I have single domain , and if i am accessing with ip , it should access via ip only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add another condition (`RewriteCond` directive) to prevent the redirect happening when an IP address has been requested:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^\d
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

When the *host* does not start with `www.` and does not start with a numeric digit.

Note that you'll need to clear your cache before testing, as the `<ip>` to `www.<ip>` redirect is likely to have been cached by the browser.

Although it would perhaps be more usual to canonicalise the URL and *redirect* the IP address to the domain name?

Comment: Probably not the ideal condition, you could have a perfectly valid domain starting with a digit. Probably want to ensure the host is composed solely of digits and dots instead (and colons if supporting IPv6).

Comment: @jcaron Admittedly this is assuming the OP's domain does not start with a digit. If the OP's domain does not start with a digit then the above regex (that would fail on the first character) is more efficient, particularly since this ruleset is executed on every request. If the OP's domain starts with a digit then check the 2nd char, etc. However, you'd never need to check that the whole host looks like a valid IP address - that just adds unnecessary complexity.

Comment: As far as I understand it, the OP wants to redirect **any** domain without the starting `www.`, it's not a matter of a single domain (if that were the case, then it would be much simpler, just match on the domain itself, rather than match on hosts not starting with `www.`, and IP addresses would never be matched).

Comment: Well, I took "any domain.com _request_" to simply mean "any request to domain.com"? `domain.com` being the example domain, not literally `<anydomain>.com` - I think we need clarification from the OP. It's also covered by an SSL cert. I had also assumed that by requesting the IP address they would be accessing the _same site_ which would imply they have just one domain. And they later refer to "my domain" and "my site" - which also implies just one. If they do have multiple/variable parked domains on the same account then yes they might need to be more specific with this condition.